# Populating an array with data from a promise and using that array within functions (Javascript, Angular, Node, SQL)

Tags: javascript, sql, angularjs, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to create a Cards Against Humanity clone in an attempt to solidify my understanding of the MEAN stack. I'm very new to Angular and asynchronous programming so please bear with me.

So far I've created a shuffled deck of cards via a GET request, but now I'd actually like to use that data.

I'm populating an array like so:

```
self.blackCardDeck = [ ];

getCards();

function getCards(){
    $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/cards'
    }).then(function(response){
    self.blackCardDeck = response.data;
    });
}
```

This code is getting all of the card data from my database, and then populates the array (my shuffled deck). Rather than simply using this in my html, I'd like to be able to use this array in other functions.

For example: I'd like to create a function that uses this deck, slices 6 cards, and sets this new array to the cards that a player is holding.

Something like:

```
function player(playerName) {
  this.playerName = playerName;
  this.currentCards = [];
}

player1 = new player("Player 1");

var playerArray = [player1, player2, player3, player4];

for (var i = 0; i < playerArray.length; i++) {
 self.playerArray[i].currentCards = self.blackCardDeck.slice(0, 7);  
}
```

Obviously with the way my code is currently, that's not possible.

Could someone give me some suggestions on where to go from here?

I know I could populate a JSON file with the card information, but I really need to practice async and working with databases. Additionally, I'd eventually like to give users the option to create custom decks, which would potentially require a database(?).

So far, I haven't worked with services or $q. I was looking into this article (https://coderwall.com/p/uqqraq/angular-promises-basics-q-service-for-http) and it looks like maybe something like this is what I'm looking for?

Any recommended reading/general recommendations on my code is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Obviously with the way my code is currently, that's not possible." why is that obvious? You are assigning data to an array, you can do with it what you want. It looks to me like you might want to await the return from the GET and maybe you're not doing that before trying to use the deck. So have the GET cb emit (see a library like eventemitter), and on in any service or controller that cares to act on it write the code you'd like in listeners there.

Comment: I say 'obviously' because I can't get my code to work! It seems obvious to me because I've spent hours trying to work with it, but I probably shouldn't have phrased it like that. 

I was looking into await before I got sidetracked with $q, but I'll definitely look into await/emit! Thanks so much for the advice!

Comment: @ArrielleKooiman why you don't call the functions to split the cards inside your success callback? I don't understand what is the point of your question.

Comment: @CarlosArauz I run into a different issue if I do it this way (which maybe should have been the route I tried to solve in the first place). But basically if I call the for loop and give the players cards within the success callback - I'm not sure how to make sure they can't REDRAW the same card in the next round. The reason I was trying to solve it the way listed above, is because it seemed easier for me to figure out which cards have been 'drawn' and cut them from the deck array. Any thoughts?